# Plot from a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I want to create a multi-plot from each array of matrix `y`:

```
q = [...] % (a 1x6 matrix)
p = [...] % (a 6x6 matrix)
x = [0:1:40];
y = q * p ^ x;
```

But I get this error:

```
Error using  ^ 
Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix.
To compute elementwise POWER, use POWER (.^) instead.
```

Comment: [http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/matrices-and-arrays.html](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/matrices-and-arrays.html)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid blow-ups in power computations, do not compute the powers explicitly but instead use intermediate results

```
y = zeros(41,6);
y(1,:) = q;
for ind = 1:40
    y(ind+1,:) = y(ind,:)*p;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
q = [...] ( a 1x6 matrix)
p = [...] ( a 6x6 matrix)
x = [0:1:40];
y = [] ;
for i = 1 : length (x)
    y(i,:,:) = q * p .^ x(i);
end
```

`q * p` will generate the matrix of size of **6 x 6**. y will be 3 dimensional matrix of size of **41 x 6 x 6**.

Answer (score 0):

try to fix this line as

```
for k=1:40
y = q * p ^ k;
end
```

also you can do this as

```
for k=1:40
y = q * p ^ x(k);
end
```

also it will takess power of p as x then multiple `q * p ^ x;`